# path of folder within a folder in terminal

Tags: command-line, files, find

I have a number of files that are saved as

```
Year -> Month -> Day -> bunch of .nc files
```

I would like to generate a list of all of the directories that contain the nc files. I can list the path of each nc file with:

```
find /Year/ -name *.nc | sort > directory_list.txt
```

which finds each .nc file in the sub directories of these folder in this main file. These results are then saved in a text file 'directory_lists'.

```
/2000/01/01/nc_file1.nc
/2000/01/01/nc_file2.nc
/2000/01/01/nc_file3.nc
/2000/01/02/nc_file3.nc
/2000/01/03/nc_file3.nc
```

and so on...
How is it possible to slightly modify this so that I have a list of each 'Day' directory? This would be similar to the results I get with the command above, but without the information on the nc file included.

I have tried:

```
find /Year/ | sort > directory_list.txt
```

but this returns each path

```
/Year/
/Year/Month
/Year/Month/Day
```

I would like the outcome to be:

```
/2000/01/01/
/2000/01/02/
/2000/01/03/
```

and so on... without the directory name being repeated

I think this is the same as trying to get the directory of the third level folder within the Year directory? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /Year/ -name '*.nc' | sed -e 's:/[^/]*$:/:' | sort -u
```

Will give you the list of directories which contains at least one file whose name match '*.nc'

Comment: This is nearly what I need. I need another '/' at the end, so that I can end up inside the final directory. Is there a way of adding '/' to the end of the string?

Comment: @EmmaTebbs, updated to keep the final `/`.

Answer (score 0):

`egrep '/[^/]+/[^/]+/' directory_list.txt`

This gives you all lines that contain exactly 3 `/`, which happens to be the directory depth you want.